# How can I make mathematically-based bulk changes to a large JSON file?

Tags: python, json

Let's suppose that I have directory of several names like the following:

```
{
    "name": "Miller John",
    "mobile": "897654321",
    "age": 45,
    "salary": 120000,
    "address": {
        "city": "New York",
        "country": "USA"
    }
}
```

I want to now divide the salary field by ***k*** for every person and replace the current salary by that salary divided by ***k***. For a very large JSON, how do I do this?

---

EDIT:

The actual code that I'm working on is an NDJSON with several items, the first of which is the following:

```
{"index":{"_id":1}}
{"name":"Wine - Maipo Valle Cabernet","price":152,"in_stock":38,"sold":47,"tags":["Alcohol","Wine"],"description":"Aliquam augue quam, sollicitudin vitae, consectetuer eget, rutrum at, lorem. Integer tincidunt ante vel ipsum. Praesent blandit lacinia erat. Vestibulum sed magna at nunc commodo placerat. Praesent blandit. Nam nulla. Integer pede justo, lacinia eget, tincidunt eget, tempus vel, pede. Morbi porttitor lorem id ligula.","is_active":true,"created":"2004\/05\/13"}
```

I'm trying to divide the price field by 10.

Comment: What programming langage do you use?

Comment: I suppose I could manage with Python. Still learning though.

Comment: OK, I'm adding the correct tag, then! That will bring awareness to the Python gurus.

Comment: @SteeveDroz: Thanks! 

Also, for whoever is reading, the file in question that I'm dealing with is an NDJSON.

Comment: This may give you an idea... https://stackoverflow.com/a/53474079/2836621

Comment: The NDJSON spec states that each line should be a valid JSON object (the code you pasted isn't NDJSON, btw). Accordingly, you could tackle this line by line: (i) open an input and output file (ii) for each line of input, construct a Python dict from the JSON (iii) update the dict as you see fit (e.g. `obj['salary'] /= K`) (iv) write the object out as NDJSON to the output file...make sure to respect the NDJSON spec while writing out

Answer (score 1):

You could use `jq` in your Terminal like this:

```
jq '.salary= (.salary/1000)' YourFile.json
```

**Output**

```
{
  "name": "Miller John",
  "mobile": "897654321",
  "age": 45,
  "salary": 120,
  "address": {
    "city": "New York",
    "country": "USA"
  }
}
```

Comment: I got the following error: jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER, expecting $end (Windows cmd shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
'.price=
jq: 1 compile error

Comment: Please see my edit of the question statement, which includes information from the exact file that I'm using. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

just loop and divide by K

```
K = 10
data = [{
    "name": "Miller John",
    "mobile": "897654321",
    "age": 45,
    "salary": 120000,
    "address": {
        "city": "New York",
        "country": "USA"
    }
}, {
    "name": "Miller John1",
    "mobile": "8976543211",
    "age": 41,
    "salary": 333,
    "address": {
        "city": "New York",
        "country": "USA"
    }
}]

for entry in data:
    entry['salary'] = entry['salary'] / K
```

Comment: The JSON is very large, so presumably reading it all into memory at once is prohibitive.